# TypeError: comment_detail() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'request' and 'slug'

Tags: python, django, django-views

I got error

`path('post/<int:id>/comments', comment_detail(), name='comments'),`

`TypeError: comment_detail() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'request' and 'slug'`

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .forms import CommentForm
from .models import Post


class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'

    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 2
    queryset = Post.objects.all()

class BlogDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'

class BlogCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_new.html'
    fields = ['title', 'author', 'body', 'header_image']

class BlogUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_edit.html'
    fields = ['title', 'body', 'header_image']

class BlogDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

@property
def image_url(self):
    if self.image:
        return getattr(self.photo, 'url', None)
    return None

def comment_detail(request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.get(Post, slug=slug,)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.post = post
            obj.save()

            return redirect('detail', slug=post.slug)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()

    context = {
        'post': post,
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request,'post_detail.html', context)
```

**post_detail.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
    <link href="{% static 'css/post_detail.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <div class="post-entry">
        <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ post.body|urlize }}</p>
    </div>

    <p><a href="{% url 'post_edit' post.pk %}">+ Edit Blog Post</a></p>
    <p><a href="{% url 'post_delete' post.pk %}">+ Delete Blog Post</a></p>
    {% if post.header_image %}
        <p><img src="{{post.header_image.url}}"></p>
    {% else %}
        <p></p>
    {% endif %}


    {% for comm in post.commentpost_set.all%}
        {{ comm.user }} <br>
        {{ comm.text }} <br><br>
    {% endfor %}

    <article class="content" >

        <br><hr>


        <form method="post" action='{% url 'comments' %}'>
            {% csrf_token %}

            {{ form.as_table }}
            <div class="container height-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div class="card p-3">
                    <h4>Add comments</h4> <textarea id="textarea" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    <div class="mt-3 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"> <span id="count"></span><br><button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Submit</button> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </article>

{% endblock content %}
```

Here is the template I am using

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add more details.
Okay, I'll add some text, what a stupid feature I don't understand, which prevents me from asking questions normally

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

Answer (score 0):

```
path('post/<int:slug>/comments', comment_detail, name='comments'),
```

Two issues in that line, the `comment_details` shall be a function pointer not a function call, the variable name shall be `slug`

Here is the problem

```
 <form method="post" action='{% url 'comments' %}'>
```

You didn't pass the slug, so you shall make it optional parameter and add a url with no parameters.

add this to urls.py

```
path('post/comments', comment_detail, name='comments'),
```

In views.py

```
 def comment_details(request,slug=None):
```

Comment: there was another error
`django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'comments' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<slug>[0-9]+)/comments$']`

can i show models, views, urls, post_detail and other necessary files for you to see?

Comment: The problem in a {%url%} tag in the template

Comment: no, I'm telling you, this error appeared

`django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'comments' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<slug>[0-9]+)/comments$']`

Comment: That is another error, share the template you are rendering

Comment: i added a template

Comment: Check updated answer, don’t add another error in this question